# How does this method compute Rational(1).hashCode()? The numerator or denominator of 1 is 1 itself

Tags: java, hash

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this Rational object.  That hash code is
 * derived from the hash codes for its two components.  This design
 * decision ensures that two Rational objects that are equal will have
 * the same hash code.
 * @return An integer hash code for this object
 */

public int hashCode() {
    return new Integer(num).hashCode() ^ (37 * new Integer(den).hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Rational` is not part of standard Java. A Google search reveals it might be part of an external library, but you haven't told us which one so we can't really say anything about its behavior.

If `Rational` has a constructor that takes a single `int`, I would expect that it provides a default denominator of `1`, so it is perfectly reasonable to calculate a hash code using the method you quoted.

The default `Integer#hashCode()` method just returns the integer itself as the hash code, so the value returned would be `0x00000001` xor'ed with `0x00000025`, or `0x00000024` (36 decimal).